# Are all node.js modules server-side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

Is there front-end node modules or all are server-side unless packaged using `browserify` and similar tools?

Comment: [Some node modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery) are simply convenience packages to front-end libraries. [Some node modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/virtualbox) use APIs that are not available in the browser and never will be. What _exactly_ are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.js modules are designed to be used with Node.js.

You might run Node.js as a server side environment. You might run it as a command line program. You might run it as an HTTP client in its own right.

Node.js does not run inside a browser. Node.js modules are not generally designed for use embedded in a webpage using `<script>` elements.

It is *possible* to write a hybrid JavaScript file that can function both as a Node.js module and as a script in a webpage … but there isn't often a good reason to do so. (I've done it once: To write a client for a particular webservice that I wanted to use in a browser and in a Node.js program).

Browserify can convert *some* Node.js modules so they can run in a browser.